# Trying to make an Applescript to open webpages added to Reading List

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, bookmarks

I would like to automatically open download links in Safari that I remotely add to the Reading List.  It is easy to add to the Reading List in iOS, and the changes are instantaneous on my computer.

My idea is to use a Folder Action Applescript to watch for new files added to  /Library/Safari/ReadingListArchives/

New alphanumeric folders are added there containing "Page.webarchive" files and if possible "ReaderPage.webarchive"

My script is based of an existing Folder Action, "add - new item alert".
Please know that this is my first attempt to code; here it is:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
try
    tell application "Finder"
        --get the name of the folder
        set the folder_name to the name of this_folder
    end tell

    tell application "Finder"
        --go to the desktop 
        activate
        --open the folder
        open this_folder
        --select the items
        reveal the added_items
        --select the items
        tell application "System Events"
            set item_list to POSIX path of file "Page.webarchive" of added_items
        end tell
    end tell

    tell application "Safari" to open POSIX file item_list
end try
end adding folder items to
```

This code successfully opens the new alphanumeric folder containing the webarchive.  Continuing, I have been trying to code a prompt for Safari to open the page.  My understanding is to open the file, the POSIX path is needed.  I tried to name that path and direct Safari to it.  This probably makes quite evident I have no experience, so thanks to anyone who has advice.

I have also unfortunately noticed that direct download links don't show up here despite showing up in the Safari side panel, and I wonder where those exist.  This code will probably also be useful to watch and open those links.

Is there a location to watch for Reading List additions which cannot be saved as a webarchive, like direct file links?  And following my code, how can I command Safari to open the new file brought to focus by the Applescript?

Thanks so much,
Kenny

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    repeat with aFolder in added_items
        set archivePath to (aFolder as text) & "Page.webarchive"
        try
            tell application "Safari" to open archivePath
        end try
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```